# Where to place one single html page in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have few html pages from my old site that I want to place somewhere on the server where my Liferay theme is and link to those from my Liferay site. Where to save these pages?

I created one folder under the _diffs folder named 'HTML', put the html pages there and did the linking from there. It works well, but I was wondering if I am allowed to play with the folder structure of my theme like this? If not, how to approach this?

Thanks in advance.
Adia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are having a web server in front of the liferay portal for e.g.: Apache, I would prefer to keep those HTML files in apache documentRoot and access it from there keeping liferay themes clean.
2. If you are using Liferay 6.1 you can check a feature called Liferay Sync. It allows you to share documents. I have not used it yet.

HTH